# VPU and PHPunit installed with composer

Tags: php, phpunit

I use PHPunit and would love to use [VPU](http://nsinopoli.github.io/VisualPHPUnit/) as a nice visual test runner but I'm having problems getting it to install. I have followed the relatively straight forward directions but am getting:

```
 PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
```

In other discussions it appears there were a number of problems with multiple version of PEAR or php.ini's (largely related to MAMP and similar stacks being divergent from the CLI). In any case, unless I'm wrong, I believe installing PHPunit via PEAR is discouraged these days and will be discontinued at some point. The modern way is via through Composer and I would think that would then afford you the luxery of leveraging Composer's `autoload.php`.

Anyway, my question is ... has anyone gotten VPU working with PHPUnit 4.x where the install was a composer-based install? If so, can you help me to do the same?

Comment: Installing PHPunit via PEAR was discontinued last month.

Comment: Well there you go ... we need a modern VPU install procedure. :)

Comment: You could raise a ticket - I [think this is the repo](https://github.com/meazuri/VisualPHPUnit). Or you could fork the code and add Composer support. Maybe get in touch with the author to see if they will merge it in?

Comment: they've turned off issue raising feature. As for doing it myself ... I wish I had the time. Hoping to not reinvent the wheel here. Surely someone's already done the hard work?

Comment: Someone might have added Composer, but my guess is they haven't - it is hardly forked and not starred at all on GitHub. You could try searching the whole web to see if there are any blog articles or comments about it, but otherwise you'd need to add it. I presume adding Composer support is trivial though? Isn't it just adding a JSON file and then registering the library on Packagist?

Comment: I'm certain it won't be that easy but I understand your pessimism about there being an existing "wheel" out there. :)

Comment: Why not try contacting the author another way?

Comment: I'm open to it but quick search on twitter didn't get me anywhere. Ideas?